# full farm backup for Moss 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

We have 4 WFE servers 2 application servers and 3 Sql servers. I want to take full farm backup.
I have to do some very critical activity on the farm, hence in case of failure i will be able to restore my farm again.

Could you please suggest me best approach for this..

Environment: Moss 2007, sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Their are couple of approaches you can follow.

### Back up a farm by using built-in tools

You have to manully apply the all the customization and AAM settings.

- [Back up a farm by using Central Administration (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262946(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Back up a farm by using the Stsadm command-line tool (Office
  SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263004(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Restore a farm by using built-in tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262426(v=office.12).aspx)

### Back up a farm by using SQL Server tools

in this approach you have to rebuild the farm and configure the SSP and web apps, deploy all the customization and apply the AAM settings. At then end attach the database to web apps.

- [Back up a farm by using SQL Server tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263069(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Restore a farm by using SQL Server tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262197(v=office.12).aspx)

Third option is using the 3rd party backup & recovery tool.

few help full resources:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/demo-back-up-office-sharepoint-2007-HA010268974.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447593(v=office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262412(v=Office.12).aspx